# Python Join tables and return default text for ID's which are not found

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data-frames as shown below,

```
df1
Id
1
2
3
4
5

df2
id   val1
1    1
3    
4    0

df3
id   val2
1    1
5    
4    0
```

My output dataframe should have all the Id's present in df1 and I am looking to join df1 with df2 and df3. If the ID is not found in the dataframe, then put in the text saying "IDNP" else return whatever the value is present on the corresponding column.

IDNP - Implying ID not found.

This is my expected output.

```
Final DataFrame
id   val1    val2
1    1        1
2   "IDNP"   "IDNP" 
3            "IDNP"
4     0       0
5    "IDNP"
```

I have more than 100 columns in df1, df2 and df3 with 100000 records. So performance is also a concern here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a LEFT OUTER JOIN (`merge` with `how='left'`).

```
(df1.rename({'Id': 'id'}, axis=1)
    .merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
    .merge(df3, on='id', how='left')
    .fillna('IDNP'))

   id  val1  val2
0   1     1     1
1   2  IDNP  IDNP
2   3        IDNP
3   4     0     0
4   5  IDNP
```

---

As an alternative, you can use `pd.concat` to perform an outer join on the "id" as an index.

```
(pd.concat([df2.set_index('id'), df3.set_index('id')], axis=1)
   .reindex(df1.Id, fill_value='IDNP')
   .reset_index())

   Id  val1  val2
0   1     1     1
1   2  IDNP  IDNP
2   3         NaN
3   4     0     0
4   5   NaN
```

Comment: I am trying the 2nd method (pd.concat) and it fails - Shape of passed values is (2, 131869), indices imply (2, 131805). can you help me on this please.

Comment: @Sid29 What about the first method? I am not sure what the problem could be, because it depends on your data. Could you try to reproduce the problem and open a follow-up question please?

Comment: will do. the first one worked for me. But it freezed the system in the middle like after 25 secs.